# LINQ query to Group, Sort and SumProduct

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

How to create a `LINQ` query to achieve the following:

1. Group source data items by *Name* property
2. Sort the resulted `Groups` by *Value* property, largest group on top
3. Select the group items into a new class called *MyNewClass* (described in the below image, on the right-hand side)
4. Calculate `SumProduct` of *Value* x *Maturity* for each `Group` and set the result to *MaturitySumProduct* property in *MyNewClass*.

Below an example of the source data and the desired result structure from the `LINQ` query.

[image]

I started with grouping in a LINQ query but got stucked with the rest:

```
Dim query = From i In SourceDataItems
            Group By Name = i.Name
            Into MyNewClass = Group
```

How to complete the query to get the desired result?

Comment: What is `SourceDataItems`?

Comment: It is the source data, as IEnumerable of a custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming an appropriate constructor in  `MyNewClass`:

```
Dim query = From i In SourceDataItems
            Group By Name = i.Name Into NameGroup = Group
            Let SumArea = NameGroup.Sum(Function(i) i.Area)
            Let SumValue = NameGroup.Sum(Function(i) i.Value)
            Let SumMaturity = NameGroup.Sum(Function(i) i.Maturity)
            Let MaturitySumProduct =  NameGroup.Sum(Function(i) i.Value * i.Maturity)
            Order By SumValue Descending
            Select New MyNewClass(Name, SumArea, SumValue, MaturitySumProduct)
```

Comment: Works otherwise but SumProduct calculation is wrong. I need multiplication on the source data item level, for example for Item1 I need: 2334 x 23.2 + 2331 x 45.2 = 159 510. Now it calculates it as (2334+2331)*(23.2+45.2) =319 086

Comment: If you make one more edit, I can accept the answer: i.Value + i.Maturity -> i.Value * i.Maturity